# Only the Else condition is executed not the if condition

Tags: c#

```
private void ifsc_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
        string query = "select * from ifsc where branch='" + branch_txt + "'";
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(conString);//connection string already defined
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            OleDbDataReader myReader;  //declared myReader
            myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();//executes query
            if(!myReader.Read())
            {
                string scode = myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("ifsc_code"));//get the ifsc code from database
                code.Text = scode;
            }
            else
            MessageBox.Show("No Data Found!");  //error message while no data found              
            conn.Close();
            myReader.Close();  //closing both connection and myreader
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);// exception
        }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: what is the result. add those into your question

Comment: Error appears : "No data exists in row/column"

Comment: Does your query itself return good results when run in Management Studio or elsewhere?

Comment: we are doing in the Visual Studio 2015

Comment: Run your query directly against the database in an appropriate tool, e.g. in Access if this is an Access database. That will solve the problem for you I guess.

Comment: This is an access database. How to run in access?

Comment: `GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("ifsc"))` you are using table name instead of column name here

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in this line

```
string scode = myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("ifsc"));
```

you are referring the table name instead of column name
change "ifsc" to corresponding column name

Comment: changed column name and added database again. still same error apppears

Comment: in ur question still the column name is "ifsc" its the table name from where you are pulling the data..can show the table columns of "ifsc"??

Comment: Please check now

Comment: did u run the query in access and got result?

Comment: how to run in access

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your if statement to:

**if(myReader.Read())**

use it without ! sign.

Comment: problem not in `if` statement, problem in common logic. @David you can rewrite original code with `while` statement.